# VB.net Console Application crashes when trying to save a .pfd with PDF Box

Tags: vb.net, pdf, pdfbox, ikvm

Im trying to change a PDF file with the PDFBox Library in vb.net,
evrything went fine until i was trying to save the PDF, it crashes with the following stacktrace:
org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.COSVisitorException wurde nicht behandelt.

```
  HResult=-2146233088

  Message=java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for MessageDigest(provider: SUN)cannot be found.

  Message (Exception)=java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for MessageDigest(provider: SUN)cannot be found.

  Source=pdfbox-1.8.7

  Source (Exception)=pdfbox-1.8.7

  StackTrace:

       bei org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.write(PDDocument doc)

       bei org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save(OutputStream output)

       bei org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save(File file)

       bei org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save(String fileName)

       bei PDFAnfertigen.Module1.TextAusPDFAuslesen(String pPDFPfad) in C:\Users\fengels\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PDFAnfertigen\PDFAnfertigen\Module1.vb:Zeile 44.

       bei PDFAnfertigen.Module1.Main() in C:\Users\fengels\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PDFAnfertigen\PDFAnfertigen\Module1.vb:Zeile 12.

       bei System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)

       bei System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)

       bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()

       bei System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)

       bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)

       bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)

       bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

       bei System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

  InnerException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException

       HResult=-2146233088

       Message=class configured for MessageDigest(provider: SUN)cannot be found.

       Message (Exception)=class configured for MessageDigest(provider: SUN)cannot be found.

       Source=IKVM.OpenJDK.Core

       Source (Exception)=IKVM.OpenJDK.Core

       StackTrace:

            bei sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(String type, Class clazz, String algorithm)

            bei java.security.Security.getImpl(String , String , String )

            bei java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(String algorithm)

            bei org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.write(PDDocument doc)

       InnerException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

            HResult=-2146233088

            Message=sun.security.provider.MD5

            Message (Exception)=sun.security.provider.MD5

            Source=IKVM.Runtime

            Source (Exception)=IKVM.Runtime

            StackTrace:

                 bei IKVM.NativeCode.java.lang.Class.forName0(String name, Boolean initialize, ClassLoader loader)

                 bei java.lang.Class.forName0(String , Boolean , ClassLoader )

                 bei java.lang.Class.forName(String className, CallerID )

                 bei java.security.Provider.Service.getImplClass()

            InnerException:
```

I have no idea what this means and googling it ain´t that effective, this is my Code, even i think it has nothing to do with it

```
Dim objPDFDokument As PDDocument = PDDocument.load(pPDFPfad)
        Do
            eingefügt = False
            While intSeite < objPDFDokument.getDocumentCatalog.getAllPages.size
                Dim Dateipfad() As String = NachDateiZuordnungSuchen(intSeite, pPDFPfad)
                If Dateipfad IsNot Nothing Then
                    For Each strDateipfad As String In Dateipfad
                        If Path.GetExtension(strDateipfad).Equals(".pdf") Then
                            Dim objPDFeinfuegDatei As PDDocument = LadePdf(strDateipfad)
                            For i As Integer = 0 To objPDFeinfuegDatei.getDocumentCatalog.getAllPages.size - 1
                                eingefügt = True
                                intSeite += 1
                                objPDFDokument = FuegeSeiteEin(objPDFDokument, objPDFeinfuegDatei, intSeite)
                            Next
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
                intSeite += 1
            End While
        Loop Until eingefügt = False

        objPDFDokument.save(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(pPDFPfad), "test.pdf"))
        objPDFDokument.close()
```

Comment: PDFBox is a java lib. If you use it in a .net environment, you are probably using some tool, e.g. IKVM. You should add that one as tag. Btw the current pdfbox version is 1.8.8 (this isn't the cause of your problem, but I mention it because 1.8.7 was a not-so-good version).

Comment: It looks like your IKVM is missing the class `sun.security.provider.MD5`. I don't know the project so I don't know if it should have it, you should probably try to reach and ask [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/), anyway it doesn't look like a PDFBox issue.